How to Display tkinter image without transparent background
Having trouble displaying  image (PIL/tkinter).  Image displays but with transparent background.
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

path = "zzz.png"

root = tk.Tk()
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
panel = tk.Label(root, image = img)
panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")

root.mainloop()

I want background to be opaque.
I noticed that this is only an issue in a gnome3 desktop; where the program launches from a gnome-terminal.
Another update.   Only issue when running desktop remotely using xrdp.  Following link shows similar issue:
https://github.com/neutrinolabs/xrdp/issues/1906   However; I am not able to get xrdb working in 24bit color depth mode.
screenshot of program's output  displayed on an xrdp desktop.   image that may be used in program.

Different implementations of tkinter have different ways of handling transparency.  If you want to display an image with an opaque background, convert the image first with an image editing program.

Use JPG instead of PNG. A normal PNG can have opacity so I'm not actually sure this needs to be a coding solution. I think you just need to change your asset like @PaulCornelius noted

@PaulCornelius  works fine when logged in directly to linux box => not an implementation issue.  Problem only shows up when  logged in remotely using xrdp
same behavior with jpg.  Really think it's an xrdp issue.

yes, RDP programs can pick up the fourth channel even if the local graphics system doesn't respect the fourth channel during composition. that can happen on any system. I've personally observed that with screen capture programs as well. they use the same techniques to capture the screen or individual windows.


How to Display tkinter image without transparent background

Try this without using PIL namespace.

Add this wm_attributes before mainlioop().

Snippet:
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

path = "p2.png"

photo = tk.PhotoImage(file=path)
tk.Label(root,image=photo,bg='grey').pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")

#your other label or button or ...
root.wm_attributes("-transparentcolor", 'grey')
root.mainloop()

screenshot:


This does not work for me; I get the following error message:
tkinter.TclError: bad attribute "-transparentcolor": must be -alpha, -topmost, -zoomed, -fullscreen, or -type
Please note;  I think the issue is with xrdp.   my code  works when logged in directly to the linux box or though an ssh connection with X11 forwarding.

Please edit your your question
